# Changing Eclipse Default Formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, coding-style, formatter

In eclipse, I have a java code style formatter prepared (saved as xml). Every time I start a new project, I need to manually set the formatter in preferences to my format. I regularly need to make new projects (in separate workspaces), and it is getting very annoying setting the formatter each time.

Is there any way to change the default format that is loaded when a new Eclipse workspace is opened? I think there may be a plugin to do this, but I don't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: You could also keep a "template" empty workspace and always start from that, instead of letting eclipse create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences and import the xml you have, this will be taken for all eclipse projects...
[image]

for sharing eclipse specific settings across workspaces:

Go to

> ${old_workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings

Copy everything under the above directory to

> ${new_workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings

This is going to make sure that the ${new_workspace} is having the same configuration as the ${old_workspace}

and the formatter file can be found at

> ....metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
>   ....metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs

just search for the key **formatter_profile**

Comment: OP seems to want a default for every new *workspace*, not just for every new project.

Comment: jap, now is the information completed. @RealSkeptic

Comment: I recently came across this solution for also copying all formatting in general. It just seems a bit ridiculous that there isn't an easier way to set these defaults on new workspace creation.